# HTML Div overlays

Tags: html, overlay

I want a code for html overlays like thickbox, that is worked in all browsers.

can u please tell the related urls or something else...

regards
KK

Comment: Please, be more specific about the problem. Where can we see a good example of "overlays"?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of *box scripts around.
I'm sure none of them works in *all* browsers that exist, but most of the mainstream solutions like Thickbox itself should behave well in all *major* browsers which is the best you can ask for.

Check out these lists:

- [Thinking Outside The LightBox – TOP 10 PICKS](http://www.attackr.com/thinking-outside-the-lightbox-top-10-picks-part-1/)
- [30 Scripts For Galleries, Slideshows and Lightboxes](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/) at Smashing magazine

for anything more specific, you would have to go into more detail.

Comment: tx...but my exact requirement is ... i have to place jcrop module on the thickbox (or) lightbox (or) greybox..

how can i do this?

Comment: What is the jcrop module? Please amend this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I made my own lightboxing stuff and here is what I'm using that is working back to IE6 for sure. You just make a div and append it directly to the body. You need to make a png image that is translucent to use as your background.

```
html, body{height:100%;}

#lightbox_darkLayer{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    _top: expression(((ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop)) + 'px'); 
    _left: expression(((ignoreMe2 = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft)) + 'px');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:url(/images/overlayBg.png) repeat;
    z-index:1001;
    _filter: alpha(opacity=70);/*This is for IE6 who won't support a translucent png as a bg image*/
}
```

The css properties prefixed with underscores are for IE. You could do this cleaner by adding some CSS to IE specifically using their [html comment if check thing](http://dustinbrewer.com/css-trick-target-only-ie-with-an-if-statement/).